# Prevent C# from encoding brackets in query string

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, request

I need to consume a service that takes a GET parameter named "names[]".

For example: `GET http://example.com/name2id?names[]=john`

When I try to consume that in C# using a WebClient, the brackets gets encoded to %5B%5D, which the servies does not understand. When I send the above using my browser (un-encoded), everything works fine.

Heres the example that does not work:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://example.com/name2id?names[]=john"));
}
```

Monitored by fiddler, heres the request:

```
GET http://example.com/name2id?names%5B%5D=john HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Is there any way to make the framework NOT encode the URL, or some other way around this issue?

P.S. I do not control the API so I cannot change that.

**UPDATE:**

This is kinda wierd. I found a solution, changing my C# code to:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://example.com/name2id?names[]=john", true));
}
```

Note the boolean `dontEscape` in Uri. It is actually deprecated, but it works? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I think the only way around is to not use a WebClient but do a manual request using a normal socket, but even then it wouldn't really be a valid request so i'd wonder if the service would accept it

Comment: You could always ask the provide to use reasonable names in their arguments, and of course verify that they really do require "[]" in the name. This requirement seems pretty ridiculous to me.

Comment: Guess it's deprecated because it allows you to create an invalid URI. But since you need an invalid URI I'd ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by CodeInChaos, the URL is not valid according to RFC2396.

To make C# not escape invalid characters, the overloaded method of URI can be usen:

```
new Uri("http://example.com/name2id?names[]=john", true)
```

However, this method is deprecated but apparently it still works. I have to live with the warning popping up :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand RFC2396 [] are not valid characters in a URI. So it looks to me like your service expects a malformed http request.

```
query         = *uric
uric          = reserved | unreserved | escaped
unreserved    = alphanum | mark
mark          = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"
reserved      = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
escaped       = "%" hex hex
```

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Comment: That is true, but it's what the service expects, and I cannot change that. It does work through a browser, and I actually found a solution. I will update the question.

Comment: RFC 3986 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) lists brackets as reserved characters. However, "reserved" means they're only *eligible* for special treatment, depending on server requirements. This is a major problem with all current HTTP options in .NET in 4.5, as they all escape the URI at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the encoded characters is the real problem?

The characters are encoded correctly by the WebClient class. If the service can't handle characters that are correctly encoded, then the service is broken.

If the service is broken in that way, and you have to use it anyway, then you have to find a different way of sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

techincally its correct to url encode `[]` to `%5B%5D`, so the problem is not using [] but that the provider doesn't correctly url decode the path/querystring

http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to pass the URI as a string

So doing

```
 response = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/name2id?names[]=john");
```

Should work without encoding the url.

Haven't tried it though so i might be wrong.