# Special Characters In URI

Tags: c#, zip, uri

I have a zip file that I'm trying to read the contents of, which has all gone well up until I needed to read a file named `[Content_Types].xml`. When I try to create a new URI, it tries to convert the brackets to something url-friendly, which results in a file name that doesn't match.

I'm using `System.IO.Packaging.Package` to read the zip, which requires a URI when trying to read part of the package with `package.GetPart()`.

How can I create a URI that will leave the brackets intact for reading the file from the package?

To clarify what I'm trying to do here, Office Open XML files (.docx, .xlsx, .pptx, etc) are actually zip files with a different extension. If you rename a file of one of those extensions to .zip, you can see the contents of the Office file structure. One of the files included in the root of every Office Open XML file is one called `[Content_Types].xml` I have a need to modify that specific file.

Comment: Using a normal ZIP component would make much more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible.

According to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), characters such as `[` and `]` are in the "unwise" category because gateway and other transport agents are known to modify them.

Regardless, [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) is a bit more explicit on the subject:

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
>   [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
>   within square brackets ("[" and "]").  **This is the only place where
>
>   square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.**

So, the only way you could use square brackets is if the code you are relying on failed to meet RFC specifications.

I'd probably try to use the `package.GetParts()` method to iterate through the parts and output their URIs.  It would be interesting to see what that returns for your special file.

Comment: I just tried this out and the one file I need isn't included in the resulting collection, even though I can clearly see it in the package. Of course.

Comment: @HotN: That's just full of awesomesauce.  At this point I'd say pick a different zip file parser.  I think the MS "programmer" responsible for the packaging class should be taken out back and beaten with a clue bat.  There's no reason to force URIs in that thing.

Comment: Awesomesauce indeed. I should have given in much earlier and went 3rd party. DotNetZip did the trick with a fraction of the headache.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloaded URI constructor that accepts a boolean dontEscape, which should prevent the brackets from being escaped.
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419001/prevent-c-sharp-from-encoding-brackets-in-query-string)

Edit based on rereading the updated question:
So from some googling, it looks like [Content_Types].xml is a file that turns a zip file into a "zip package". Coincidentally, `System.IO.Packaging.Package` only works with zip packages (not regular zip files). It also only writes zip packages (always including [Content_Types].xml). I do not think you can get directly at [Content_Types].xml through `System.IO.Packaging.Package`, by design.

Comment: Hmm, every variation I try ends up with a UriFormatException - Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. I've tried with slashes, without slashes, with preceding @.

Comment: The method used in that question was deprecated.

Comment: @HotN - I was able to get it to work in cases where the URI did not open with a bracket - for example, `@"C:\[Content_Types].xml"` worked